# Как совместить селектор?

Tags: css3, css

В общем мне надо, чтобы при наведении мышки на .head и  .foot у #label_text изменялся стиль, работает только  1 строчка

```
 .head:hover #label_text,

.head:hover #label_text,
.foot:hover #label_text {
    color: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.47);
    text-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, я понял, что Вы имели в виду, но как назло у меня снова всё работает, смотрите [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/LeD4eG/CkEqf/)

Возможна ошибка в разметке страницы - перепроверяйте.

PS в своём тестовом примере добавил несколько элементов для наглядности!

Comment: .head #label_text:hover 
так оно будет менять стиль у .head и #label_text, а мне надо, что-бы меняло стиль у #label_text, при наведении курсора на .head

Comment: Вы сами сейчас поняли что именно написали?
у `.head` никаких стилей изменяться не будет. будут меняться стили для `#label_text`, который является дочерним по отношению к элементу с классом `.head`, при наведении на него. если я что-то не так понимаю, то приведите ещё краткую html-разметку, чтобы точно понять что именно Вам нужно.

Comment: мне надо, что бы стиль у #label_text, менялся при наведении мыши на .head
<div class="head">
<p id="label_text"></p>
</div>

Comment: перейдите по ссылке и Вы увидите, что стиль меняется. я ведь указал источник

Comment: ZoZexZero, обязательно #label_text должен быть дочерним по отношени. к .head или .foot?

Comment: короче у мя ошибка была, в том что   #label_text был не вложенным в .foot

Answer (score 0):

Во первых не должно быть на странице 2-ух элементов с одинаковым id, а во вторых попробуй так:

```
.head:hover #label_text,
.foot:hover #label_text {
    color: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.47) !important;
    text-shadow: white 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: в моём примере работает и без `!important`...в чём смысл его  употребления в данном случае?

Comment: в твоём примере вообще нет стиля который может перекрыть данный, но в вёрстке ZoZexZero вполне может быть